# Reading Excel file with multiple sheets

Tags: excel, matlab, repeat, import-from-excel, data-import

I have an Excel file which contains 4 sheets.

Each sheet has the same format but the data inside is different. For example:

```
sheet1:
              sub1 sub2 sub3

    person1    2    3     4
    person2    9    0     1
    person3    8    4     2

sheet2:

              sub1 sub2 sub3

    person1    5    7     8
    person2    1    3     7
    person3    4    1     3
```

Now, I know how to read the data for 1 sheet:

```
[data, titles] = xlsread(FileName, 'sheet1');
```

But when I don't know how many sheets I have in my document, how can I store all data from all sheets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`xlsfinfo`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsfinfo.html) to get a list of the sheets and then loop over that list:

```
[status,sheets] = xlsfinfo(FileName)

for s = 1:numel(sheets)
    ...
    [data,titles]=xlsread(FileName,sheets(s))
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop is unnecessary. The [`importdata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) function (introduced before R2006a) can handle this scenario with ease. For example, I had an excel file with 5 sheets containing data as below:

[image: Sample data]

As you can see, it contains text, numbers and blank spaces. On R2017b, calling

```
xlsData = importdata('name-of-file.xlsx');
```

results in a `struct` containing two fields: `data` (for numeric values, holding `double` arrays) and `textdata` (for text, holding `cell` arrays), each having fields that correspond to worksheet names in the Excel file.